# jQuery - Repeating same actions on different DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like I’m violating a lot of DRY rules here but can’t think of a better way to do this. I have two event methods (there are actually four total just showing two) that are doing a lot of similar actions but on different DOM elements. Is there a better way to re-factor this so I’m not repeating myself so much.

```
    $('.user .expandDetails a').on('tap', function () {
        var expandWrapper = $('.userFooter');
        if ($('.userInfo .details').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.userInfo .details').addClass('active').slideDown();
            $('.userInfo .expandUserDetails').removeClass('down').addClass('up').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.userInfo .expandUserDetails').removeClass('up').addClass('down').removeClass('active');
            $('.userInfo .details').removeClass('active').slideUp();
        }
    });

    $('.user .paymentDetails a').on('tap', function () {
        var expandWrapper = $('.paymentFooter');
        if ($('.paymentInfo .details').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.paymentInfo .details').addClass('active').slideDown();
            $('.paymentInfo .expandPaymentDetails').removeClass('down').addClass('up').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.paymentInfo .expandPaymentDetails').removeClass('up').addClass('down').removeClass('active');
            $('.paymentInfo .details').removeClass('active').slideUp();                                      
        }
    });
```

Please include code samples where applicable somewhat new to jquery.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you are violating some DRY rules, so lets clean it up. First, I would cache some of the selectors you're calling.

```
var $info = $('.userInfo');
var $details = $info.find('.details');
var $detailsExpand = $info.find('.expandUserDetails');
```

Then I would take a look at some of the toggle options that jQuery offers, mainly:

- [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
- [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

This will save you the trouble of having to use `.addClass`, `.removeClass`, `slideUp`, and `slideDown`.

For example, you have:

```
if ($('.paymentInfo .details').is(':hidden')) {
    $('.paymentInfo .details').addClass('active').slideDown();
    $('.paymentInfo .expandPaymentDetails').removeClass('down').addClass('up').addClass('active');
} else {
    $('.paymentInfo .expandPaymentDetails').removeClass('up').addClass('down').removeClass('active');
    $('.paymentInfo .details').removeClass('active').slideUp();
}
```

We can remove that else statement, and just let our new toggle methods handle the adding/removing.

```
if ($details.is(':hidden')) {
    $details
        .toggleClass('active', true) // true means the class will be added
        .slideToggle();

    $detailsExpand
        .toggleClass('down', false)  // false means the class will be removed
        .toggleClass('up', true)
        .toggleClass('active', true);
}
```

Lastly, and this might be overkill, you could try creating a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.toggleDetails = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        infoClass: null,
        expandClass: null
    }, options);

    var $info = $(settings.infoClass);

    var $details = $info.find('.details');
    var $detailsExpand = $info.find(settings.expandClass);

    if ($details.is(':hidden')) {
        $details
            .toggleClass('active', true)
            .slideToggle();

        $detailsExpand
            .toggleClass('down', false)
            .toggleClass('up', true)
            .toggleClass('active', true);
    }
};
```

And then applying your new plugin would be as easy as calling the `.toggleDetails` method on your selected elements, and providing both an `infoClass` and `expandClass`.

```
$('.user .expandDetails a').toggleDetails({
    infoClass: '.userInfo',
    expandClass: '.expandUserDetails'
});

$('.user .paymentDetails a').toggleDetails({
    infoClass: '.paymentInfo',
    expandClass: '.expandPaymentDetails'
});
```

Caveats:

- This code hasn't been tested.
- I'm not sure how to assign a `down` or `up` to `slideToggle`. I would have expected a similar `true`/`false` parameter similar to `toggleClass`.